# Application Self installation broadcast receiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcast

I am creating an android library and i need to inform my server that the application have been installed. So is there any broadcast receiver that will be called once my application is installed in android device.

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't trigger any code upon installation finish. There will be some intent fired, but you wunt be able to catch it so far.

Answer (score 1):

You will not get any broadcasts unless user manually start your app after installation.  And if s/he does, then you can easily notify your server.

Answer (score 0):

You could send the signal to the server as soon as your app is openend the first time. Many users will opend the app right after it is installed, so this should not make a huge difference.

Just check a `boolean` stored in `SharedPreferences` in your MainActivity's `onCreate()`. If it is not set, send the signal to the server and then set it to true. If it is already true, this is not the first start of the app.

Comment: Thanks for your response but i am creating a android library where the developers will add my library as module in their project. I am new in android and i want to know whether there is any broadcast receiver that will be called once my application installed in mobile device.

Comment: You could force your users to call a init() funtion of your library in the Application's onCreate().

Answer (score 0):

You can register for the broadcast MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED to get notified once the update version of the application is installed.
Refer: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#ACTION_MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED